# Error in Php SDK Facebook - Strange Error

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

```
  if(isset($basic)){
    function meme(){
    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists("pg/".$i.".jpg")){
    $file[$i] = "pg/".$i.".jpg";
    $i++;
    }
    }
    $file[1] = 'pg_1.jpg';
    $file[2] = 'pg_2.jpg';
    $file[3] = 'pg_3.jpg';
    $file[4] = 'pg_4.jpg';
    $file[5] = 'pg_5.jpg';
    $file[6] = 'pg_6.jpg';
    $file[7] = 'pg_7.jpg';
    $file[8] = 'pg_8.jpg';
    $file[9] = 'pg_9.jpg';
    $file[10] = 'pg_10.jpg';
    $file[11] = 'pg_11.jpg';
    $file[12] = 'pg_12.jpg';
    $file[13] = 'pg_13.jpg';
    $file[14] = 'pg_14.jpg';

    $tuomeme = 'pg/'.$file[rand(1, 14)];
    $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'CiaoCiao',
            'name'=> 'CiaoCiaoCiao'
    );
    $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details) or die("Errore nella connessione con Facebook");
    $album_uid = $create_album['id'];
    $photo_details = array(
        'message'=> he(idx($basic, 'name')).''
    );
    $finale=$tuomeme;
    $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($finale);
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details) or die("Errore nella connessione con Facebook");
```

**bold** The error are:

> [18-Jun-2012 19:30:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/xtigbexz/public_html/dev/index.php:27) in
>   /home/public_html/sdk_php/facebook.php on line 7 [18-Jun-2012 19:30:32
>   UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/public_html/dev/index.php:27) in
>   /home/xtigbexz/public_html/sdk_php/facebook.php on line 7 [18-Jun-2012
>   19:30:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't
>   open file ""
>
> thrown in /home/public_html/sdk_php/base_facebook.php on line 423

Can you help me? Please!

Answer (score 0):

Line 27 of your file `/home/xtigbexz/public_html/dev/index.php` is generating output. You're calling the Facebook API after that, which is trying to set a `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE` variable. You can't set either of those after your script has generated some output.

Comment: And for this: [18-Jun-2012 19:30:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "" ?

Comment: You're passing an empty string where there should be a file called. PHP's error messages can be cryptic sometimes. The root cause of this error could be the same issue that's giving you the first error.

Comment: Dude, please get some basic PHP knowledge & debugging skills, instead of letting your problems get solved here one by one after another …

Comment: Yes, i have resolved it, but i don't know hot to make resolved this topic.

Comment: There is an outlined check mark next to this answer. Click it and it will turn green. That marks this topic as resolved.

Comment: @zic how did you fix the problem? I am facing the same issue.